# Spring boot : access rest api from @Scheduled method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I try below guild of schedule-task and it worked.

http://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

next, I want to access web-api from `@Scheduled` annotated method, and add below dependency to my build.gradle, to use `RestTemplate`.

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.1.RELEASE'
```

but, below Exception occurs.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
at my.pkg.Application.main(BatchApplication.java:14)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)

do I need specific setting to use `RestTemplate` from `@Scheduled` method ?

my full build.gradle is below, other files are same to guide.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.1.RELEASE'
  // below line I added.
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.1.RELEASE'
}
```

Comment: Post the entire exception message, not just the exception's class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web` is intended for web applications that need a servlet container. It's overkill if all you need is `RestTemplate`. Replace the dependency with one on `org.springframework:spring-web`

Comment: I add  `compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.5.RELEASE'` and it works, thanks!